# Can I open Overleaf project in LYX?

Tags: lyx, templates, overleaf

I have a thesis project  that I began in Overleaf, taken from the ready templates.
I want to move to Lyx in order to work offline. The source file from Overleaf is a .zip that contains Chapters (.tex files), Figures (.png), .bibtex files etc...
I can open the separate *.tex files of the template but Lyx does not seem to support the whole template format.
Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: You can [import LaTeX in LyX](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Compatibility) but you would be better off using a [LaTeX editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) to edit your project offline.